# PHP bing api html content translation response displays as plain text

Tags: php, character-encoding, translation, bing

The html content after translating from bing, display as plain text with all html tags visible. I am using the code from here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512421.aspx#phpexample
How can i convert it to display as html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appending contentType="text/html" to the querystring as in http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?oncomplete=yourfunction&appId=yourAppID&from=lang1&to=lang2&text=yourHtml&contentType=text/html

Ref: [URI parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512406.aspx)